# Google VM instance initialised by itself

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

After the VM initialised, all my stuff in the VM is missing, is there any way to retrieve them back?

[This is the VM that got removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny9WJ.png)

[Now it is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbZrg.png)

[And this is when it initialized without my permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8I69.png)

I have a billing set up for the account and project, however, the project just initialized without me setting up anything for that

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck8fv.png)

The violation is due to my card not working and causing the payment to not go through, but it was fixed and paid and still not working

Comment: Please provide more details about your use case: **1**. Do you use [12-month, $300 free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial)? **2**. Do you have  billing activated for your project?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza I had set up the billing for the project, it pays every month and for 2 months when I was using it, it was fine until recently

Comment: So, you have billing enabled for your project for 2 months and everything was okay until recently, am I right? Do you have any records at ACTIVITY tab like "Delete instance"?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza No, it just mentioned initialize instance and the stuff in it was gone

Comment: Do you have any log records?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza I updated my question to include the log

Comment: I think you should contact with [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support) because of quite limited amount of data you provided.